# How to fix Installer has Insufficient privileges to access directory?

Tags: xamarin

I have already log on **administrator** but **xamarin** give installer has Insufficient privileges to access directory

The installer has insufficient privileges to access this **\ directory: C: \ProgramData \Monodoc.** The installation cannot continue. Log on as administrator or contact your system administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Access C: \ProgramData using file explorer

2) Right Click folder and select property

3) Select Security tab

4) Check 'Full Control' for Administrator

[image]